# Why doesn't the text from a SwiftUI Label appear in the Xcode 15 string catalog?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, localization, xcode15

When I use Xcode 15 beta 3 to add a string catalog to an existing project (created with Xcode 14) and then build the current scheme, the resulting Localizable.xcstrings file doesn't contain any text from SwiftUI `Label` views.  It does contain text from `Text` views, navigation bar titles, and various other views, but nothing from `Label`.  My labels are declared like this:

```swift
Label("Hello world", systemImage: "home")
```

If I create an empty project using Xcode 15 beta 3 and then add a string catalog and build, the text from a `Label` does appear in Localizable.xcstrings.

What is stopping the text from `Label` appearing in the string catalog when the project was created with a previous version of Xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project created with Xcode 15 beta 3 has the `SWIFT_EMIT_LOC_STRINGS` setting defined in the project build settings.  Without this setting, Xcode will only extract string literals in `Text` initializers.  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference#Localized-String-SwiftUI-Support).

Adding `SWIFT_EMIT_LOC_STRINGS` to the build settings of my existing Xcode project fixed the problem.